# javascript page load causing page to bump

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that uses Javascript to switch between subpages in the form of divs.  The problem is that when I click between the subpages, the entire page frequently gets shoved upward and hides one of my navigation bars.  This happens in all browsers.

http://www.victorsheckels.com

The relevant parts of the page are:

```
<div id="main" class="content" style="position:absolute; top:64px; left:176px; right:32px; bottom:32px;z-index:11;visibility:hidden;overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden">
<div id="book" class="content" style="position:absolute; top:64px; left:176px; right:32px; bottom:32px;z-index:12;visibility:visible;overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden">
<div id="copyright" class="content" style="position:absolute; top:64px; left:176px; right:32px; bottom:32px;z-index:13;visibility:hidden;overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:hidden">

    <script>
function getSub() {
    var section = location.hash.slice(1);
    if (section == 'about') showMain();
    if (section == 'library') showBook();
    if (section == 'copyright') showCopyright();
}


function showMain() {
    hideBook();
    hideCopyright();
    document.getElementById("main").style.top = "64px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("mainnav").style.background = "rgba( 255, 153, 0, 0.3)";
    document.getElementById("mainnav").style.borderBottom = "#FF9900 1px solid";
}

function hideMain() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.top = "100%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("mainnav").style.background = "rgba( 255, 153, 0, 0)";
    document.getElementById("mainnav").style.borderBottom = "#009900 1px solid";
}

function showBook() {
    hideMain();
    hideCopyright();
    document.getElementById("book").style.top = "64px";
    document.getElementById("book").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("booknav").style.background = "rgba( 255, 153, 0, 0.3)";
    document.getElementById("booknav").style.borderBottom = "#FF9900 1px solid";
}

function hideBook() {
    document.getElementById("book").style.top = "100%";
    document.getElementById("book").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("booknav").style.background = "rgba( 255, 153, 0, 0)";
    document.getElementById("booknav").style.borderBottom = "#009900 1px solid";
}

function showCopyright() {
    hideMain();
    hideBook();
    document.getElementById("copyright").style.top = "64px";
    document.getElementById("copyright").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("copyrightnav").style.background = "rgba( 255, 153, 0, 0.3)";
    document.getElementById("copyrightnav").style.borderBottom = "#FF9900 1px solid";
}

function hideCopyright() {
    document.getElementById("copyright").style.top = "100%";
    document.getElementById("copyright").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("copyrightnav").style.background = "rgba( 255, 153, 0, 0)";
    document.getElementById("copyrightnav").style.borderBottom = "#009900 1px solid";
}

function showZ1Preview() { document.getElementById("bookpic").style.backgroundImage = "url('zw1.jpg')"; }

function showD1Preview() { document.getElementById("bookpic").style.backgroundImage = "url('dw1.jpg')"; }

function showD2Preview() { document.getElementById("bookpic").style.backgroundImage = "url('dw2.jpg')"; }

function showD3Preview() { document.getElementById("bookpic").style.backgroundImage = "url('dw3.jpg')"; }
</script>


.content {
  padding-bottom            : 16px; /* 1/16 */
  padding-left              : 16px; /* 1/16 */
  color                     : #CCCCCC;
  border                    : #000000 solid 1px;
  border-top                : #009900 solid 1px;
  border-bottom-left-radius : 40px;
  background                : rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition                : all 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `href="#copyright"` on the link to navigate to the copyright tab. You are jumping because you are not only firing your js, but also trying to move to an absolute positioned object.

EDIT: It's a fix, but the underlying issue is the manner in which you are laying objects out. Absolute positioning is nice at times for floating things, but it should be avoided when creating block level elements.

Comment: That seems to fix the immediate issue.  I will take your advice under consideration next time I do a major update.  :)